# How to pass values between components in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, components

So I've been stuck on this assignment for about a week now on this one part. I've asked a question about it here but due to my inexperience with React I still can't figure out how to solve it. The assignment is as follows:

> The goal of this project is to create an application that simulates
>   the operation of a cafe. You will need to create components for the
>   customer, barista, and coffee machine.
>
> **Customer component**
>
> This is the "User facing" component. Here you should have 3 option
>   items that will cause this component to fire a custom event. These
>   options are: Drip brew, french press, and espresso.
>
> When one of the objects is clicked, it should highlight and stay
>   highlighted until another is clicked.
>
> **Barista Component**
>
> This component takes the orders, and displays a response on the DOM,
>   formatted as such:
>
> "One {{ order_type }}? That will be {{ order_value }}."
>
> When taking a new order, play an animation to transition out the next
>   text, and transition in new text.
>
> After a delay of five seconds (use the setTimeout method), fire an
>   event to start the preparation of the coffee. Change the text in this
>   component to read, "Waiting for {{ order_type}}"
>
> This component also needs a method that will be called when the
>   machine finishes it preparation. This "coffeeFinished" method should
>   display a message like so: "Here is you {{ order_type }}, enjoy!".
>
> When taking a new order, play an animation to transition out the next
>   text, and transition in new text.
>
> **Machine Component**
>
> This component, when its "brewCoffee" method is called, should display
>   a message visually to the user that says "Currently brewing: {{
>   order_type }}".
>
> Again, using setTimeout, have this component wait five seconds before
>   firing a "brewingComplete" event. When this event is fired, also
>   change this component's output to "{{ order_type }} is done."
>
> While the coffee is brewing, a loading bar needs to be animated to
>   display how much time until the process is over.
>
> **The Application Object**
>
> The application object will be responsible for listening for each of
>   the events fired from your components, and calling the appropriate
>   methods on the next in line. For instance, when the Machine Component
>   fires the event "brewingComplete", the application should respond to
>   the event by calling the deliver order method on the Barista
>   component.
>
> Additionally, this component should store the current order name in
>   its properties. This is the variable that should be referenced when
>   displaying the order being brewed and repeated by the barista.

The problem I've been having is taking one component, in this case when a user pushes a button, and using those values in the other components with the timeout function. What I have so far is:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './Customer.js';
import Customer from './Customer.js';
import './Barista.js';
import Barista from './Barista.js';
import './CoffeeMachine.js';
import CoffeeMachine from './CoffeeMachine.js';

class App extends Component {

  //The State with all the stuff that gets updated along the way
  state = {
    coffee: "",
      value: 0,
      bgColor: 'transparent'
  }


  //I apparently can't comment in the render thing without it appearing on the page. So, the Green box for the Customer Component, the Orange box for the Barista Component, and the Blue Box for the Machine component.
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">

          <div className="row" id="green">

          <Customer order = {(coffeeSelect, value) => {this.send(coffeeSelect, value)}}/>
          </div>


          <div className="row" id="orange">
          <Barista coffeeSelect = { this.state.coffee } value = { this.state.value }/>
          </div>


          <div className="row" id="blue">
          <CoffeeMachine coffeeSelect = { this.state.coffee } value = { this.state.value }/>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  //Sends the selected values to the other components
  send(coffeeSelect, value) {
    this.setState({coffee: coffeeSelect, value: value});
  }



}

export default App;
```

**Customer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Customer.css';

class Customer extends Component {


//Each button has a div to be highlighted upon being selected
    render() {

        return(
            <div>

            <div className="button">
            <button onClick={() => { this.optionSelect("Drip")}}>
        Drip
        </button>
        </div>

        <div className="button">
        <button onClick={() => { this.optionSelect("French Press")}}>
        French Press
        </button>
        </div>

            <div className="button">
        <button onClick={() => { this.optionSelect("Espresso")}}>
        Espresso
        </button>


            </div>

        </div>);
    }


    //Receives the brew, and assigns it to its matching cost
    optionSelect(userChoice) {
        var coffeeSelect = userChoice;
        var value = 0;

        if (coffeeSelect === "Drip"){
            value = 5;
        } else if (coffeeSelect === "French Press"){
            value = 6;
        } else if (coffeeSelect === "Espresso"){
            value = 3;
        }

        this.props.order(coffeeSelect, value);
        console.log(coffeeSelect);
        console.log(value);



    }



}

export default Customer;
```

**Barista.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Barista extends Component {

    //The default text in the Barista Component until the user sends it the coffee and cost
    state = {
        text: "Hello, How May I Help You Today?",
        orderText: "One " + this.props.coffee + "? That will be $" + this.props.value
    }

    //This is where I've hit the brick wall. I just need to get the buttons to also call this thing but everything I've looked up just gives me errors. If I could figure out where to call this I can do the timer to "prep" the coffee.
    confirm(){
        this.setState({ text: "One " + this.props.coffee + "? That will be $" + this.props.value});
        setTimeout(() => {this.waiting()}, 5000);
    }

    waiting() {
        this.setState({ text:"Waiting for " + this.props.coffee});
        setTimeout(() => {this.finish()}, 5000);
    }

    finish() {
        this.setState({ text: "Here is your " + this.props.coffee + ". Enjoy!"});
    }


    render() {

        return(

            <div>

            {this.state.text}



                </div>
        )

    }


}

export default Barista;
```

As by this point I am completely stuck, I don't have anything for the machine component yet. While I have no doubt that I have a multitude of problems here, my main problem is when a user presses a button in the customer component how to change the text in the barista component. Is there something simple I am missing or am I completely off the mark?

Comment: do you have a repo with the full code?

Comment: Since this is an assignment, I don't want to give the answer, however, what you want to utilize is a `HOC` or Higher Order Component. The `HOC` will be like the coffee shop itself. It houses all the `children` components, and can share things as well  (you actually have the foundation for this setup as `App`). However, you need to elevate `state` and/or `methods` that need to be utilized and shared across the children. You're close. You have the foundation for it, you just need to utilize it more. Also, in the `render` method, you can insert comments like so: `{ /* I'm a comment! */ }`.

Comment: you should use some state management like redux because it think thats what they want from you, though you could do it withour redux.

Answer (score 1):

You're falling victim to the most classic of all React problems. Instead of **reacting** to state changes, you are only rendering the view based on an **initial** state.

This super simple change will fix your problem:

```
// Barista.js

....

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {"One " + this.props.coffee + "? That will be $" + this.props.value}
    </div>
  )
}
....
```

Now when your parent state changes from clicking the button in `Customer` the `Barista` render method will show the updated message because `this.props.value` has changed.

**Note**: your props aren't named correctly.. in `App` you called it `coffeeSelect`:

```
<Barista coffeeSelect=
```

.. but in `Barista` you called it `this.props.coffee` so make sure to name your props the same. In `App` it should be:

```
<Barista coffee=
```

Comment: This is what I had initially before trying to add the timer part. (Although I did miss the props naming, thanks for that.) The problem with this is that the text on render is "One ? That will be $0." It needs to either be blank or have something like "How may I help you today?" and then change to the "That will be $" once the user presses a button.

Comment: so use conditional rendering https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html have you read the docs at all?

Comment: I might not be understanding that doc correctly. When I apply the conditional I receive the error "Maximum update depth exceeded" after clicking a button in the Customer component. From what I understand it's because the render just keeps repeating over and over again due to the conditional. I'm trying to do it so where if the value of coffee is just the empty string then it will display the welcome message and upon having a value it will change to the order and the price string.

Comment: can you update your question with the "conditional rendering" code you added? maximum update depth being exceeded does not occur from conditions.. it occurs because you are calling setState in the render cycle somewhere

Comment: Updated. The example they use in the doc is adding a button so I tried to adapt it to instead of changing a button to changing the text in the div.

Comment: After looking at the doc for hours on end I finally figured out what it was wanting from me. Now the only issue is that I have to press the button twice for anything to work.

Comment: for hours? sorry I can post a clear response today. can you update your question now with the newest code?

Comment: I figured it out. I posted it as an answer and I figured out why it was taking two button presses. By hours I just meant that I was just trying to figure out how to adapt the example the doc used for what I needed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Fixed the problem with having to press the button twice.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class Barista extends Component {

    //The default text in the Barista Component until the user sends it the coffee and cost
    state = {
        text: "Hello, How May I Help You Today?"

    }

    //The domino effect of messages. Upon being sent the brew and value variables, the confirm function is called which calls the waiting function which calls the finish function.
    confirm(){
        this.setState({ text: "One " + this.props.coffee + "? That will be $" + this.props.value});
        setTimeout(() => {this.waiting()}, 5000);
    }

    waiting() {
        this.setState({ text:"Waiting for " + this.props.coffee});
        setTimeout(() => {this.finish()}, 1000);
    }

    finish() {
        this.setState({ text: "Here is your " + this.props.coffee + ". Enjoy!"});
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {
        if (this.props.coffee !== null && this.state === nextState) {
            setTimeout(() => {this.confirm()}, 3000);
        }
    }

    render() {

console.log(this.props.coffee);

        return(

            <div>

            {this.state.text}

    </div>
    )
    }
}

export default Barista;
```

Comment: this is a very bad solution and a major anti pattern in react. your'e trying to update state in a child that should be stored in the parent using a hack like componentWillUpdate

Comment: What is an anti pattern? Also are you saying that I should be using a function in the App that calls something in the Barista?